# How do I hide a column in an asp:Table?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a simple ASP.NET table like so:

```
<asp:Table id="tbl">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow id="header">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell id="hcell1" />
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow id="row">
        <asp:TableCell id="cell1" />
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

The ID's are made up and the actual table has several more columns. I want to be able to hide any column programmatically from the codebehind (not javascript). Is this possible? At this point I can easily change the markup to be pretty much whatever I want, so I'm open to suggestions.

EDIT: Sorry to be clear. I want to be able to simply hide a column in such a way that if I add a new row I don't want to have to change any of the code that handles the hiding. The ideal would be something like:

```
tbl.Columns["ColName"].Visible = false;
```

Less ideal would be a for/foreach loop that did something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this extension method, it extends the Table class, adding methods to hide columns by index and by the ID of a TableHeaderCell (if one exists):

Note however, that it does not provide any logic to cater for columns which span other 
columns:

**Examples**

```
tbl.HideColumn("HeaderID");
tbl.HideColumn(0);
```

**Class**

```
public static class TableExtensions
{
    public static void HideColumn(this Table table, int index)
    {
        foreach (TableRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells.Count-1 >= index)
            {
                row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void HideColumn(this Table table, string id)
    {
        int index = 0;
        bool columnFound = false;

        if (table.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            TableHeaderRow headerRow = table.Rows[0] as TableHeaderRow;
            if (headerRow != null)
            {
                foreach (TableHeaderCell cell in headerRow.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.ID.ToLower() == id.ToLower())
                    {
                        columnFound = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    index++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(columnFound)
            HideColumn(table, index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put runat="server" on all the tags, and then in code behind you can do [control id].Visible = false;

Answer (score 1):

Markup:

```
<asp:Table id="tbl" runat="server"> <---!
    <asp:TableHeaderRow id="header">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell id="hcell1" />
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow id="row">
        <asp:TableCell id="cell1" />
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Code-behind:

```
foreach(TableRow row in tb1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Columns.Count >= x + 1)
        row.Columns[x].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: setting `cell1.Visible = false;` will only hide that cell. I want to hide the column. Also I'd prefer that I can use a name for the column without having to rely on magic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on using the built in Delete/Edit/Select commands and you want to hide an id column you would be better off stylistically hiding it.

Here is the function I use

```
static public void HideColumn(GridView gv, int columnIndex)
{
    if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[columnIndex].Style.Add("display", "none");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            row.Cells[columnIndex].Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Alongside this guy

```
static public int GetColumnIndex(GridView gv, string columnName)
{
    int returnMe = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (gv.Columns[i].HeaderText == columnName)
        {
            returnMe = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return returnMe;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the response from @jdavies, the code below also works in case we have column span specified for any column. Also, the code is enhanced to work to either show or hide columns as required.

```
 public static class TableExtensions
{
    public static void ShowOrHideColumn(this Table table, int index, bool bShowColumn)
    {
        foreach (TableRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var colIndex = 0;
            var actionCol = 0;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (colIndex == index)
                {
                    row.Cells[actionCol].Visible = bShowColumn;
                    break;
                }
                colIndex += cell.ColumnSpan == 0 ? 1 : cell.ColumnSpan;
                actionCol++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ShowOrHideColumn(this Table table, string id, bool bShowColumn)
    {
        int index = 0;
        bool columnFound = false;

        if (table.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            TableHeaderRow headerRow = table.Rows[0] as TableHeaderRow;
            if (headerRow != null)
            {
                foreach (TableHeaderCell cell in headerRow.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.ID != null && cell.ID.ToLower() == id.ToLower())
                    {
                        cell.Visible = bShowColumn;
                        columnFound = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    index += cell.ColumnSpan == 0 ? 1 : cell.ColumnSpan;
                }
            }
        }

        if (columnFound)
            table.ShowOrHideColumn(index, bShowColumn);
    }
}
```

This code will also work for variable column span specified in different rows of the table.